# How to set absolute paths for DLLs in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2019

Does anyone know how to set an absolute paths for Windows DLLs that my application is using?

I'am using Process Monitor tool and it shows me that for some DLLs (Secur32.dll,WTSSAPI32.dll,DEVOBJ.dll,WINSTA.dll,WinSCard.dll),

search result is "NAME NOT FOUND" in directory where is application installed, but from $(SystemRoot)\SysWOW64 searching result is "SUCCESS".

So it means that application for listed dll's is not using absolute path's and OS is searching for dll's from his default search order.

[image]

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Comment: These are operating system DLLs, you can't force their name/path.  Process Monitor merely shows the way the OS locates such DLLs, the folder that contains the EXE is always searched first, the OS install directory next.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: Except the application directory is not searched for known DLLs (e.g. sspicli.dll for a 32-bit process) or API sets. After the implicit imports at startup, we can remove the application directory (and current directory and PATH) from the default search via [`SetDefaultDllDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories), or via flags with individual `LoadLibraryExW` calls.

Comment: If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system checks only for redirection and a manifest before resolving to the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system does not search for the DLL. The advantage of using $(SystemRoot) is that if the disc letter should be changed (for example adding another disc), the lookup still works. Otherwise, there is no significant difference between the two forms.